Docker-Wordpress-php-nginx-mysql- Localhost:80 502 Bad Gateway Error
I have seen similar questions and solutions here before but they were not a solution. I want to run a wordpress site on local using docker but it doesn't work. I get “localhost did not send any data ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE”. I edited the codes according to the comments. Now im getting 502 Bad Gateway error. I would appreciate if you can help me how to solve it. You can find my two related code files at the end of this post.
When I type docker-compose up -d I get the output:
docker-compose up -d
When I type docker-compose ps I get the output:
ps
Docker:
dockerss
nginx.conf
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

docker-compose.yml
 services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress_db
      MYSQL_USER: wp_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp_password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress_db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wp_user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wp_password
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - wordpress

volumes:
  db_data:
  wp_data:



You need to share the wp_data volume with both wordpress_php and  wordpress_nginx containers.  2) You need to expose port 3306 on wordpress_db container and port 9000 on wordpess_php container. Additionally, I don't see where you add your nginx config to nginx container, or open HTTP port for it, your docker-compose.yml looks like a somehow trimmed one.


hi ivan, i edited codes but now im getting 502 bad gateway nginx/1.27.2 error. how can i solve?

At least:

as of 2024.11.14 wordpress:latest tag maps to 6.6.2-apache which is definitely not the image you want to use with nginx. I think you need something like wordpress:6-fpm (WordPress 6.6.2 and PHP-FPM 8.2 as of 2024.11.14);

expose port 3306 from MySQL container and port 9000 from WordPress container (see What is the difference between docker-compose ports vs expose).

map your wordpress_data volume as /var/www/html for wordpress container (as it is right now) and as /usr/share/nginx/html for nginx container.



This setup will use Docker Compose to orchestrate the containers. Here's a comprehensive guide to set up your WordPress environment:
Docker Compose Setup for WordPress with Nginx and MySQL
docker-compose.yml
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress_user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress_pass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress_db
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress_db
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress_pass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - wordpress

volumes:
  wordpress_data:
  db_data:

nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

docker-compose up -d

http://localhost


can you check all container's are running ||
docker-compose ps

now im getting the 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.27.2 error. Can you help me?
